# How to make routes work when deploying react app with nginx docker

Tags: docker, nginx

Trying to deploy react app with nginx docker and can't get subfolders working. Have read all suggestions for very similar cases here and still no result. I have docker-compose container with nginx running with custom config and port mapping 9999:80.  On attempt to visit any subfolder directly I get 404 from nginx. Attaching my nginx config.

What is in the log of nginx container on attempt to get /statistics subfolder:

```
frontend_1  | 172.21.0.1 - - [18/Sep/2019:14:01:27 +0000] "GET /statistics HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped to change listen port from defaut 80 to 8080

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```